# Solving $x^{\log(x)}=\frac{x^3}{100}$

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

How do I find the solution to:

$$x^{\log(x)}=\frac{x^3}{100}$$

So I multiplied 100 both sides getting:

$$100x^{\log(x)}=x^3$$

Now what should I do?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Take the log of both sides. You will get a quadratic equation in $\log x$.
 The equation is even "nice."

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Apply log on both side and try to solve

Answer (score 4):

I suppose $\log$ means $\log_{10}$? I'm not familiar with this sort of notation.
Take logarithm on both sides, and you will get $2+\log^2x=3\log x$. Substitute $\log x$ with t. And you get $t^2-3t+2=0$, therefore $(t-1)(t-2)=0$. That should do it.

Comment: Among most mathematicians, $ \ \log x \ $ means $ \ \log_e x \ $ or $ \ \ln x \ $.  (To some, there _is_ no other base worth talking about... :) ).  Here, common logarithms would be notated as $ \ \log_{10} x \ $.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner thx, I had always thought that $\log x$ = $\ln x$ only happens in Mathematica or C++ xD

Comment: It occurs in those systems for exactly the reason I mention (consider who writes programming languages).  Even going back to (_gasp!_) FORTRAN, the natural log function is written as LOG(X), while the common logarithm function is LOG10(X).

Answer (score 3):

$x^{\log(x)}=\frac{x^3}{100}$

Taking log on both sides you get :

$log(x) log(x) = log(\frac{x^3}{100})$ = log(x) log(x) = 3logx - 2log10 = 3logx -2

$\Rightarrow (log(x))^2  = 3logx -2 $

Now putting log(x) = t

$\Rightarrow t^2=3t-2$
Now you can solve for t as this is a quadratic in t. you get (t-2)(t-1) $\Rightarrow t = 2 ; t = 1$

$\Rightarrow logx = 2  \Rightarrow x = 100 $ ; and $ logx = 1  \Rightarrow x = 10$

Answer (score 0):

There are no solutions in the real numbers.

---

Edit: If, as RecklessReckoner suggests, the question was misstated and the intent was to use $\log_{10},$ then the solution can be found easily by taking logarithms.

Comment: why prince Charles?

Comment: @beginner: It's clear that the answer cannot be greater than $e^3$ because then the left side is greater than the right. For smaller $x$ it is easy to verify.

Comment: Yes, your original answer _is_ correct if you use natural logarithms.  (I did the same thing initially...)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: Thanks for the double-check. (+1 for your answer, by the way -- it's really the only one explaining the matter completely.)

Comment: The issue was on my mind, as I work with students who are increasingly bumping into "log" _not_ meaning the common logarithm.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: It blows my mind that students are taught an implicit base 10 in the first place.

Comment: There are considerably more people in technical fields who work with powers of 10, so common logarithms have more utility for them.  (Actually, natural logarithms are preferred only by mathematicians and theoretical/mathematical physicists, for the most part.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $(\log(x))^2=\log (x^{\log x})=\log (x^3/100)=3\log(x)-2$, we have $(\log(x))^2-3\log(x)+2=0$. Hence, $\log(x)=2$ and $\log(x)=1$. Therefore, $x=100$ atau $x=10$

Answer (score 0):

I am entering an answer just to point out a peculiarity of this equation, and the importance of interpreting the exponent "correctly". (This should also clarify  **Charles**' answer.)  I have graphed the quadratic functions $ \ (\ln x)^2 - (3 \ln x) + (\ln 100) \ $ in blue and $ \ (\log x)^2 - (3 \log x) + 2 \ $ in red.  Notice that the blue curve has no x-intercepts; the quadratic equation for natural logarithms yields a negative discriminant since $ \ (-3)^2 < 4 \ln 100 \ $.  So common logarithms *are* intended in this problem.

[image]

[image]

I had to use two graphs because the graph of the common logarithmic function is very shallow, but it does cross the x-axis at 100.

Comment: An amusing variant of this problem occurred to me just now: for what base $ \ a \ $ does the equation $ \ x^{\log_a x} = \frac{x^3}{100} \ $ have _exactly one_ solution? (We know it's somewhere between $ \ e \ $ and 10...)